# C# TCPClient Check connect status on client side

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a problem about tcpclient connect on client side...

how do I get the real connect status now and to reconnect if needs?

I have try some examples ,but they always retuen 'true'.....but it's disconnected in fact.

1.return TcpClient.Connected

2.return TcpClient.Client.Connected

3.return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);

4. bool notclosed = true;
   byte[] testByte = new byte[1];

   if (socket.Connected && socket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
     closed = (socket.Receive(testByte, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0);

return notclosed;

Comment: You could implement a heartbeat system. See [Stephen Cleary's article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) on TCP/IP. As he says, TCP is happy to assume the connection is still open while no data is sent, even if the connection is dead. To find out if it's dead, you have to send data.

Comment: but I have many clients, if they send data to check connect status frequently,my server will crash?

Comment: That's something for you to take up with the DoD and DARPA, who respectively funded and developed TCP/IP.